# Does MYSQL load the whole table into cache everytime?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a table, with say 1 million rows, with the first column being a primary key.

Then, if I run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='tomato117' LIMIT 1
```

Does the table ALL get put into the cache (thereby causing the query to slow as more and more rows get added) or would the number of rows of the table not matter, since the query uses the primary key?

edit:  (added limit 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing of the sort.

It will only fetch the row you selected and perhaps a few other blocks. They will remain in cache until something pushes them out.

By cache, I refer to the innodb buffer pool, not query cache, which should probably be off anyway.

Comment: He never specified that he was using the InnoDB engine

Comment: The principle is the same for other engines - they maintain their own cache of blocks off the disc (MyISAM relys on the OS for MYD files) and just the blocks you touched get read in.

Answer (score 4):

If the `id` is define as primary key, which only one record with value `tomato117`, so limit does not useful.

Using `SELECT *` will trigger mysql read from disk because unlikely all columns are stored into index. (mysql not able to fetch from index) In theory, it will affect performance.

However, your sql is matching query cache condition. So, mysql will stored the result into query cache for subsequent usage.

If you query cache size is huge, mysql will keep store all sql results into query cache until memory full.

This come with a cost, if there is an update on your table, query cache invalidation will be harder for mysql.

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/23/beware-large-query_cache-sizes/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/

Comment: regarding select *: If EVERY column is not an index, does that make it slower?
regarding update: There are regular updates (1 read, 1 update each time the home page is loaded), can you please explain how this will affect speed as its not clear. how will it be harder for mysql?

Comment: `select *` slightly slower because required fetch data from disk. And if need regular updates, query cache does not help as cache expire upon update.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner.  Reading as fast as I can, what is query cache, and why is it important?  If I had SELECT column1,column2,column5 FROM.... would that be query cache?  How much difference does query cache make on speed?

Comment: You should ask another question instead of asking everything in the comment section. And you can find similar question on SO...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'tomato117' LIMIT 1
```

When tomato117 is found, it stops searching, if you don't set LIMIT 1 it will search until end of table. tomato117 can be second, and it will still search 1 000 000 rows for other tomato117.

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0159 sec)
SELECT *
FROM 'forum_posts'
WHERE pid = 643154
LIMIT 0 , 30

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0003 sec)
SELECT *
FROM `forum_posts`
WHERE pid = 643154
LIMIT 1
```

Table is about 1GB, 600 000+ rows.

Comment: `A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL`

Comment: But if it's a primary key, will it still continue searching?  I thought primary key was unique...sorry, just a beginner.

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` is only useful if there's no index available. If there is an index, it should tell the engine how many rows match the query.

Comment: @ajreal @grahamparks, my bad. Ignored that tomato117 is primary key.

Comment: Does that code you posted mean its faster with limit 1? or is it ok without since its primary key? not sure...

Comment: if it is a primary key/indexed/unique , no need for the limit 1

Comment: I queried several times and LIMIT 1 always performs better but that doesn't necessarily mean anything. @Ronan, yup.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the word `EXPLAIN` before the word `SELECT`, it will show you a table with a summary of how many rows it's reading instead of the normal results.

If your table has an index on the `id` column (including if it's set as primary key), the engine will be able to jump straight to the exact row (or rows, for a non-unique index) and only read the minimal amount of date. If there's no index, it will need to read the whole table.

Comment: So even if I make a table with 100,000,000 rows, and each row is lots of text, say 2000 bytes each row, then so long as I have a primary index at the start, it will still be pretty damn fast? (as in under 1 second)

Comment: ^ Depends on server but in theory, yes.